# point plot for continuous and categorical varaible

Tags: r

I have 3 categorical variables (low, medium and high) and I want to plot something that looks like this from the paper Ross et al but can't work out the code. I have several reps for each treatment and want to plot their average and the SE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer online - if anyone else in the future has this issue check out: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-dot-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization